# Printar valor de uma struct por meio de ponteiros

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, struct, printf

Eu quero printar o "atributo" nome de uma struct do tipo "Pessoa", porém o `printf` retorna (null) mas eu declaro o nome da struct.
Segue o código abaixo:

```
typedef struct pessoa{
char *nome;
struct pessoa *pai;
struct pessoa *mae;
struct pessoa *filhos[4];
}Pessoa;
void imprimir_pai(Pessoa var){

printf("%s",var.pai->nome);

}

int main(void)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");





Pessoa Rosa_var;
Pessoa JPaulo_var;


Pessoa Eraldo_var;
Pessoa Jeane_var;
Pessoa Erik_var;
Pessoa Jessica_var;


Pessoa Edilson_var;
Pessoa Ninho_var;
Pessoa Joana_var;
Pessoa Jan_var;


Rosa_var.nome="Rosa";
Rosa_var.pai=NULL;
Rosa_var.mae=NULL;
Rosa_var.filhos[0]=&Edilson_var;
Rosa_var.filhos[1]=&Eraldo_var;
Rosa_var.filhos[2]=&Ninho_var;
Rosa_var.filhos[3]=&Joana_var;
Rosa_var.filhos[4]=&Jan_var;

JPaulo_var.nome="José Paulo";
JPaulo_var.pai=NULL;
JPaulo_var.mae=NULL;
JPaulo_var.filhos[0]=&Edilson_var;
JPaulo_var.filhos[1]=&Eraldo_var;
JPaulo_var.filhos[2]=&Ninho_var;
JPaulo_var.filhos[3]=&Joana_var;
JPaulo_var.filhos[4]=&Jan_var;

Eraldo_var.nome = "Eraldo";
Eraldo_var.pai = &JPaulo_var;
Eraldo_var.mae = &Rosa_var;
Eraldo_var.filhos[0]=&Jessica_var;
Eraldo_var.filhos[1]=&Erik_var;
Eraldo_var.filhos[2]=NULL;
Eraldo_var.filhos[3]=NULL;
Eraldo_var.filhos[4]=NULL;

Jeane_var.nome = "Jeane";
Jeane_var.pai = NULL;
Jeane_var.mae = NULL;
Jeane_var.filhos[0]=&Jessica_var;
Jeane_var.filhos[1]=&Erik_var;
Jeane_var.filhos[2]=NULL;
Jeane_var.filhos[3]=NULL;
Jeane_var.filhos[4]=NULL;

Erik_var.nome = "Erik";
Erik_var.pai = &Eraldo_var;
Erik_var.mae= &Jeane_var;
Erik_var.filhos[0]=NULL;
Erik_var.filhos[1]=NULL;
Erik_var.filhos[2]=NULL;
Erik_var.filhos[3]=NULL;
Erik_var.filhos[4]=NULL;

Jessica_var.nome = "Jéssica";
Jessica_var.pai = &Eraldo_var;
Jessica_var.mae = &Jeane_var;
Jessica_var.filhos[0]=NULL;
Jessica_var.filhos[1]=NULL;
Jessica_var.filhos[2]=NULL;
Jessica_var.filhos[3]=NULL;
Jessica_var.filhos[4]=NULL;


imprimir_pai(Erik_var);
}
```

E também queria saber se alguém pode me explicar como iniciar esse array com todos os elementos nulos para todas as pessoa, pra evitar repetição de código, e sem usar malloc()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `printf` retorna `NULL` porque está a fazer atribuições a mais em relação aos filhos. Repare que cada pessoa tem `4` filhos:

```
typedef struct pessoa {
    ...
    struct pessoa *filhos[4];
} Pessoa;
```

Mas quando atribui os filhos, está a atribuir `5`:

```
...
Jeane_var.filhos[0]=&Jessica_var; //primeiro
Jeane_var.filhos[1]=&Erik_var; //segundo
Jeane_var.filhos[2]=NULL; //terceiro
Jeane_var.filhos[3]=NULL; //quarto
Jeane_var.filhos[4]=NULL; //quinto
```

O que acontece é que devido à posição de memoria dos elementos, a atribuição ao `5` filho sobrepõe parte de outra pessoa que está a seguir na memoria, colocando `NULL`(0) sobre alguns dos seus valores e consequentemente destruindo o que lá estava.

Uma solução é retirar a atribuição que está a mais em todos os filhos:

```
Jeane_var.filhos[4]=NULL; //<---estas
```

Outra passa por aumentar a quantidade de filhos para `5`.

```
struct pessoa *filhos[5];
//                    ^---
```

[Veja como com `5` filhos já obtem o resultado esperado](https://ideone.com/D5Me1r)

Aqui vê que em C tem que ter um pouco mais cuidado do que com outras linguagens, pois o compilador não lhe vai avisar se tiver a fazer atribuições fora dos limites do array. Muitas das vezes, assim como nesta, nem sequer lhe dá erro de execução, apenas apresenta resultados e/ou comportamentos estranhos.